# Passenger and multi ruby instances

Tags: ruby, instance, passenger

I'm currently setting up my server and I'm wondering if Passenger should be configured in standalone mode or not.

I would like to have 2 different ruby instances because there are 2 important parts in my application which cannot be blocked each other.

I've heard that this is impossible to do it if Passenger is not in standalone mode.

In standalone mode, I would have to create 2 different instances of passenger to have 2 different instances of ruby.

Am I correct ? Is it possible to create different ruby instances if passenger is not in standalone mode ?

Comment: What do you mean by "2 important parts" in your application? How are those parts separated? Are they Rails engines? Or are you simply referring to 2 different parts in logic/workflow?

Comment: Basically it's one big application which send information to players. It's really important players can directly dialog with the application independently of what's happening on the web application. There aren't Rails engines.

Comment: Well, to my knowledge Passenger does spawning of Ruby instances automatically if the work load for an instance becomes too much. If you want to control that behaviour specifically you'd probably be better off with a [Unicorn setup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-unicorn-workers-in-a-ruby-on-rails-app)

Comment: Phusion Passenger provides just as many (if not more) ways to control process spawning as Unicorn does.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the passenger_app_group_name option: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/blob/13246f5110fb76d9ab92b64250037c7198089f2e/doc/Users%20guide%20Nginx.txt#L652-L734